# WP8 - Show MessageBox before leaving Pivotitem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, pivot

I load some quiz questions in one of my **PivotItems**.

My problem is when the user is in this PivotItem and if swipe to go to another PivotItem I want to get pop-up **MessagePrompt** before leaving this PivotItem to another, asking if the user really want to finish the quiz. I tried LostFocus event and Unloaded event but nothnig happens.

How can i manage this?

P.S. I know that the Quiz should be in another page, but I want to achieve this with pivotItems.

Comment: Hi do you know the number of pivot items exactly? will change dynamically , or it be a constant?

Comment: And what about start/stop buttons + yourPivot.IsLocked = true/false ?

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to pivots selectionChanged event

```
Pivot_SelectionChanged Event
{
if(Pivot.selectedindex==1|| 3|| 4)
{
Messagebox();
}
}
```

Assuming 2 is your pivot items index.

now if the user chooses "yes" then assign pivots selectedindex to 2

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the SelectionChanged event whenever a PivotItem is changed. Check the link for some examples from MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selectionchanged(v=vs.105).aspx

I haven't tried this out yet, but I believe the PivotItem will still change even when the pop-up occurs. So once you get the pop-up and you give the user a choice to stay on the current Pivot or go to the next, you might have to change the PivotItem programatically back to the quiz Pivot.

Comment: Still the same. The pop-up occurs but the PivotItem is already changed,and in the background it loads the content from the next PivotItem, although the MessageBox pop-up occurs. I want to stay on the current PivotItem,not to change before the user choice.

Comment: There's got to be a way to override the swipe event. If you can find that, then you'll be able to stop from loading the next pivot. I know some other commentators said to try a similar fix. But if you've found a solution, it'd be interesting to see how you got around this.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly messy way would be to preserve the currently selected Pivot Index state, and subscribe to the DragStartedGestureEventArgs using the windows phone controls toolkit.

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="pivotControl" Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener DragStarted="SelectedPivotChanging"></toolkit:GestureListener>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
            <Grid />
        </controls:PivotItem>
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>

 private void SelectedPivotChanging(object sender, DragStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pivotControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to navigate away?", "Un-Answered questions", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) 
                == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                //pivotControl.SelectedIndex = previousIndex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it has the same behavior as the LostFocus Event registered for the specified pivotItem. Although it fires the event, in the background the pivot is already changed and can't return to the same pivot if MessageBoxResult.OK is clicked